# Jquery callback function executes over and over again

Tags: jquery, function, callback

This my jquery function,

```
function getRecordspage(curPage, pagSize) {
   // code here
$(".pager").pagination(strarr[1], { callback: 
         function() { getRecordspage(2, 5);},current_page: curPage - 1, 
          items_per_page:'5',  num_display_entries: '5', next_text: 'Next', 
           prev_text: 'Prev', num_edge_entries: '1'
      });

}
```

and i call this jquery function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             getRecordspage(1, 5);
         });

</script>
```

As you see my It works fine for 1st time and my `callback function` is configured to the `current function` itself... when it gets called the `callback` gets executed over and over again.... How can i prevent this?  Any suggestion....

**EDIT:**

This is my function

```
function getRecordspage(curPage, pagSize) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
        data: "{'currentPage':" + curPage + ",'pagesize':" + pagSize + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonObj) {
            var strarr = jsonObj.d.split('##');
            var jsob = jQuery.parseJSON(strarr[0]);
            var divs = '';
            $.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
                divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>';
            });
            $("#ResultsDiv").append(divs);
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function in this case is to display the appropriate content, not do the pagination, your setup should look more like this:

```
var itemsPerPage = 5;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pager").pagination(maxNumberOfElementsHere, { 
     callback: getRecordspage,
     items_per_page: itemsPerPage,
     num_display_entries: 5,
     next_text: 'Next', 
     prev_text: 'Prev',
     num_edge_entries: 1
  });
});

function getRecordspage(curPage) {
 // itemsPerPage is the new pagSize you have now
 // code here
}
```

Comment: @Nick as you said do i have to pass value for `curPage` on page click

Comment: @Pandiya - The plugin already passes currentPage and the panel as arguments to your callback function.

Comment: @Nick `strarr[1]` and `curPage` value is null since i get this value inside `getRecordspage` function...

Comment: @Pandiya - That argument is number of elements to paginate, why would it change?  Edited to make both of these a bit clearer

Comment: @Nick i got you but what i say is the value for `maxNumberOfElementsHere` will come from my function is shown in my edit...

Comment: @Nick `strarr[1]` has a value `17` which has to be passed to `maxNumberOfElementsHere`

Comment: @Pandiya - You should move the code which determines the max number of elements into the document.ready part, this won't change and needs to be set from the start.

Comment: @nick look at my method i am getting json data from my aspx page and splitting it.... My first array contains json data and my second contains value for `maxNumberOfElementsHere `

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are calling the function in the function is causing the problem. It's causing an infinite loop, and will never end.

You need to give it an IF statement so it will end at some point.